# geochart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm looking for some guidance or an example how to do a geochart in d3.js.
I need something like [this one](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) in google charts, and turning to d3.js since I need some customization. So far the closest d3.js sample I found is [this](http://theartofasking.com/question/wjucdg6k) but the code is very long there and I am hoping to find something simpler.

Comment: You could also evaluate an image map solution, see  http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for a choropleth map? Here's a [recent example in 28 lines of code](http://bl.ocks.org/3306362).

This example uses the default projection, [d3.geo.albersUsa](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-albersUsa), which is a composite projection for the United States including Alaska, Hawaii and Puerto Rico. If you want to change the visible region, you probably also want to change the projection; [d3.geo.albers](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-albers) is good for choropleth maps because it is equal-area. The albers projection lets you set the [origin](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-albers_origin) so that you can focus on a specific part of the global, and all projections allow you to specify [scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-albers_scale) and [translate](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-albers_translate) to position the map on-screen.

If you want to display a world map, I'd also take a look at the ongoing development of the [extended projections plugin](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/geo/projection). This adds a number of useful map projections, particularly for world maps, such as the [Winkel Tripel](http://bl.ocks.org/3682676). The next release of D3 will also include some exciting new features such as three-dimensional rotation for any projection (including antemeridian cutting; try [dragging this example](http://bl.ocks.org/3788999)), [adaptive resampling](http://bl.ocks.org/3795544) and improved clipping.

As for coloring the choropleth, you can of course color geographic features however you like by redefining the "fill" style as a function of data.

Comment: thanks. what determines what region is visible in screen (e.g. continent)? Can I use country names for coloring?

Answer (score 2):

With all due respect to @mbostock and his answer, I thought I would add some additional resources for anyone coming across this question.

The example in the link provided by @Yaron Naveh appears to be a [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection). You can find out more about d3.js' Mercator projection facilities in the [d3.js API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections). @mbostock has also been kind enough to create blocks/gists for each of the projections in the API (click on the projection thumbnail image for the example). Here are the links to a simple Mercator projection [block](http://bl.ocks.org/2869760)/[gist](https://gist.github.com/2869760).

Regarding the "The Art of Asking - How are you feeling?" link, here is a little code to go with what @mbostock said about coloring using the fill style as a function of data. In this example, I am simply picking the unicode value for the first character of the country's name in the JSON file and making a CSS color from that value using "steelblue" (#4682B4 = 4620980) as a sort of seed (you will probably want to calculate shades/tints).

```
d3.json("readme.json", function(collection) {
  d3.select("svg").selectAll("path")
      .data(collection.features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()))
      .style("fill", function(d) { return '#'+Math.floor(d.properties.name.charCodeAt(0)/100*4620980).toString(16); });
});
```

You can check out the full example here as a [block](http://bl.ocks.org/4121134)/[gist](https://gist.github.com/4121134).

(@mbostock - Thank you for such a great tool!)