# Create d3 choropleth dataset

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been trying to create a D3 choropleth according to [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3306362). I've understood everything except how to create the `unemployment.tsv` which looks like this:

```
id      rate
1001    .097
1003    .091
1005    .134
1007    .121
...     ...
```

After further digging, I see that the ids are references to certain d3 graph objects. My question is whether there is an easy way to set the ids values of these ids, or will I have to do it manually?

If possible, I'm looking for a method as easy as [Google Charts](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#geo_chart).

Answer (score 4):

The `us.json` file used to draw the map has information about each counties' outline and their [FIPS code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_county_code):

```
{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[250,-204,-17]],"id":30047}
```

Each row of `unemployment.tsv` represents a single county, containing its FIPS code and unemployment rate. When the file is loaded, it is converted from an array of objects:

```
> unemployment
[{id: '1001', rate: '.097'},
 {id: '1004', rate: '.091'},
 {id: '1005', rate: '.134'},
 ... ]
```

to an object with the key as the county id and rate as the value:

```
var rateById = {};
unemployment.forEach(function(d) { rateById[d.id] = +d.rate; });

> rateById
{1001: .097,
 1004: .091,
 1005: .134}
```

(the `+d.rate` as casts the unemployment strings as numbers.)

Once that is done, coloring each county is simple, just the shape's id to find the corresponding unemployment rate in `rateById` and convert that number to a color with the `color` scale.

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(rateById[d.id]); });
```

To more directly answer your questions: you probably want to [code](http://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/convert/fipscounty.html) your county level* data with country FIPS codes and use that to color your map. If you aren't working with by county data, you could try converting it (mapping lat/long or city/state to county) or use another kind of map entirely (for a world map, see [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/clayzermk1/4121134) and the below comments).

*I don't have any sort of GIS background - every time I try to do this, I end up using an old FIPS code -> county name look up table and have to correct a couple by hand; there is probably a better source file on the NIST website that I haven't been able to find.

Comment: Thanks for your really detailed answer. Except that I'm working on international data showing countries. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094907/how-to-create-a-choropleth-of-the-world-using-d3 world map:

https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/blob/master/examples/world-50m.json

Comment: this one has an example linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648032/geochart-in-d3-js
http://bl.ocks.org/clayzermk1/4121134

basically, the same idea as the above but the country names are used to join the data to the map instead of the county fips codes.

Comment: clayzermk's block in your second comment has what I'm looking for. Thanks for the info. Please add the link to your answer so I can accept your answer.